# Demasiado el tiempo de respuesta en un procedimiento Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, optimización

Tengo el siguiente código en un procedimiento:

```
DECLARE @Temp_Entidades TABLE(Id int);
with Report(Id) as 
  (
  --primer select
  select distinct e.Id 
  from  EntidadesPersonas as ep 
        right join Entidades as e on ep.EntidadId=e.Id 
  where (ep.PersonaId in (select Id from @Temp_Prom) or ep.PersonaId is null) 
    and e.EstadoId <> 62 
    and e.Principal <> 1 
and e.UniversidadId = @p_EmpresaId )
insert into @Temp_Entidades select Id from Report;

--Segundo select
select distinct p.Nombres
from Personas as p
  inner join Estados as e on p.EstadoId=e.Id
  inner join EntidadesPersonas as ep on p.Id=ep.PersonaId
where ep.EntidadId in (select Id from @Temp_Entidades)
  and p.EstadoId<>69
```

Sucede que logro obtener en `@Temp_Entidades` un total de 145,000 datos (**y estoy usando `distinct`, lo necesito**) y tambien tengo en la tabla `Personas` un total de 15,500 datos aproximadamente; en el segundo `select` el tiempo de respuesta de mi procedimiento se extiende demasiado.

¿Algún tip o sugerencia de cómo puedo optimizar esta consulta?

Comment: Será útil si sacas y compartes el "execution plan" de la consulta (lo puedes sacar de SSMS usando la opción `Include actual execution plan (CTRL + M)`. También, sería bueno que compartas la definición de las tablas envueltas así como los índices que has definido en esas tablas. Y ya que compartistes la cantidad de registros para `@Temp_Entidades` y `Personas`, sería bueno hacer lo mismo con `Estados` y `EntitdadesPersonas`.

Comment: ...y también mas detalles en cuanto a `@Temp_Prom`. Pero, en general, me parece que sería mejor si tratas de combinar toda la logica en una sola consulta de ser posible. A veces, la idea de crear tablas temporales no es la mejor idea en cuanto a rendimiento se refiere, porque no le das la oportunidad a la base de datos de buscar ciertas optimizaciones. No siempre es así, pero vale la pena examinar eso mas de cerca.

Comment: cuando dices _se extiende demasiado_, ¿de cuánto tiempo estamos hablando? ¿estás haciendo la prueba en un servidor de producción con mucha carga de usuarios? ¿en un entorno de desarrollo aislado sin usuarios?

Answer (score 1):

Mientras esperamos que agregues más detalles pertinentes e importantes a tu pregunta, te propongo algunas sugerencias concretas.

**Resolver problemas debido al uso de un variable de tipo `table` con muchos registros**

> Sucede que logro obtener en `@Temp_Entidades` un total de 145,000 datos

El uso de `@Temp_Entidades` con tantos datos en tu segunda consulta definitivamente puede causarte problemas de rendimiento, por al menos 2 razones potenciales:

1. Tu segunda consulta probablemente encontraría un mejor plan de ejecución si `@Temp_Entidades` tuviera un índice para la columna `Id`, pero no la tiene.

   Una manera de definir un índice en el caso de una variable de tipo `table`, como lo es `@Temp_Entidades`, es al definirla de forma implícita por medio de una clave primaria:

   ```
   DECLARE @Temp_Entidades TABLE(Id int primary key);
   ```
2. Otro problema muy serio, es que cuando se usa una variable de tipo `table` en una consulta, por defecto SQL Server no tiene estadísticas respecto a esa tabla. Mas bien, SQL Server se limita a asumir que la tabla (en este caso `@Temp_Entidades`) tan solo tiene un solo registro (puedes verificar esto al examinar tu plan de ejecución actual). Esto, a su vez, puede conducirlo a escoger un plan de ejecución completamente equivocado para la consulta, ya que la tabla en realidad tiene 145,000 registros, no uno solo.

   Para que SQL Server tenga acceso a las estadísticas para `@Temp_Entidades`, tienes 2 opciones:

   1. Usar una tabla temporal en vez de una variable de tipo `table`:

      ```
      create table #Temp_Entidades (Id int primary key);
      ```
   2. O agregar la sugerencia [`option (recompile)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms181714.aspx) a la consulta:

      ```
      select distinct p.Nombres
      from Personas as p
        inner join Estados as e on p.EstadoId=e.Id
        inner join EntidadesPersonas as ep on p.Id=ep.PersonaId
      where ep.EntidadId in (select Id from @Temp_Entidades)
        and p.EstadoId<>69
      option (recompile) -- agregar aquí
      ```

**Revisar índices**

Por supuesto, puede que tengas que revisar si tienes los índices adecuados en las demás tablas. Es difícil darte recomendaciones acertadas sin tener 100% claro la relación entre las tablas y la cantidad de registros en cada una. Pero, de lo que puedo deducir, tiene sentido que definas los índices siguientes:

- `Estados (Id)`
- `Personas (Id)`
- `EntidadesPersonas (EntidadId)`
- `EntidadesPersonas (PersonaId)`
- `@Temp_Entidades (Id)`

**Formular la consulta diferentemente**

En lo personal, yo formularía la consulta un poco diferentemente, por ejemplo, usando `exists` en vez de `in`. Pero en la práctica, dudo que cambie algo, ya que, en general, SQL Server tiene la inteligencia necesaria para hacer ese tipo de modificaciones de forma automática si lo ve beneficioso.

Pero por si acaso, aquí tienes la consulta como yo la formularía en este caso:

```
select distinct p.Nombres
  from Personas p
  join Estados e
    on e.Id = p.EstadoId
  join EntidadesPersonas ep
    on ep.PersonaId = p.Id
   and exists(select null
                from @Temp_Entidades te
               where te.Id = ep.EntidadId)
 where p.EstadoId <> 69
option (recompile)
```

**Eliminar resultados intermediarios entre las consultas**

Nuevamente, es obvio que faltan detalles importantes en tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, de dónde viene `@Temp_Prom`?

Pero, de lo que sí puedo ver, me da la impresión que una sola consulta SQL hubiera sido suficiente para obtener los resultados finales deseados. Pero la has divido en al menos 3 consultas más pequeñas usando variables de tipo `table` para cargar los resultados temporales de cada consulta y pasársela a la siguiente. ¿Por qué? ¿Fue por tratar de mejorar el rendimiento?

En mi opinión, valdría la pena examinar si no se puede mejorar el rendimiento combinando las diferentes consultas. Siempre y cuando tengas definidos los índices adecuados, sospecho que esa es la mejor opción. Pero para ayudarte en cuanto a esto, es necesario que agregues los detalles que faltan a tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias desde ya... en realidad son muchas consultas que se guardan en tablas temporales(variables de tipo table). lo que mostré es la consulta que causa que demore mas...  `@Temp_Prom` también es un variable de tipo tabla temporal.. que llega a tener hasta 50 datos (ids). El objetivo fue ir filtrando... con los los join aun no me llevo bien...

Answer (score -1):

Crea indices en la o las columnas correspondientes, ya sea de la tabla `Personas`, `Estados` y/o `EntidadesPersonas`. [Crear índices únicos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187019.aspx)